# How should I change a state by onChange event in react?

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm writing a component for react frontend of my CRUD application, this component is a form allowing for update record in database. First of all I've declared state with useState without initial values

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({})
```

Secondly I fetching data form backend using useEffect

```
useEffect(
        function (){
            async function getEmployee(){
                const URL = `http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/payroll/${id}`
                try{

                    const res = await fetch(URL, {
                      method: 'GET',
                      headers: {
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      }
                    })
                    const list = await res.json()

                    setData(list)
                }catch(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            getEmployee()
        }
    );
```

and set fetched data as state. Backend send data in json format like that:

```
[{ "ID":1, "FIRSTNAME": "JOE", "SECONDNAME":"SMITH"}]
```

I have function which should change value of specific element in object in state

```
function handleChange(event){
        setData({...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
```

but insted it's adding a new value outside of object, for instance:

```
[{ "ID":1, "FIRSTNAME": "JOE", "SECONDNAME":"SMITH"}, "SECONDNAME":"MARK"]
```

Below all code of my react component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import './form.css'

function Edit(props){


    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const {id} = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(
        function (){
            async function getEmployee(){
                const URL = `http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/payroll/${id}`
                try{

                    const res = await fetch(URL, {
                      method: 'GET',
                      headers: {
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      }
                    })
                    const list = await res.json()

                    setData(list)
                }catch(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            getEmployee()
        }, [props]
    );
        console.log(data);
    function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        async function updateEmployee(){
            const URL = `http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/payroll/${id}`
            try{

                    const res = await fetch(URL, {
                      method: 'PATCH',
                      headers: {
                          'Accept': 'application/json',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    })
                    navigate(`/employee/${data.id}`);
            }catch(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        updateEmployee()
    }

    function handleChange(event){
        setData({...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    function handleCancel(){
        navigate(`/employee/`);
    }

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Edytuj paracownika</h1>
            <hr />
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>FirstName</label>
                    <input
                        name="FIRSTNAME"
                        type="text"
                        required
                        value={data.FIRSTNAME}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-control"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>LastName</label>
                    <input
                        name="LASTNAME"
                        type="text"
                        required
                        value={data.LASTNAME}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-control"
                    />
                </div>


                <div className="btn-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" className="btn-submit"/>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={handleCancel}
                        className="btn-submit"
                    >
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Edit
```

And backend modules:

```js
exports.getEmployeeById = async(req, res, next) => {


    let id = req.params.id;
    let query = `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID = ${id}`;
    let connection;
    oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
    oracledb.autoCommit = true;

    try{
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
        const employee = await connection.execute(query)
        res.status(200).json(employee.rows)
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        next(error)
    }

}
exports.updateEmployee = async(req, res, next) => {

    let id = req.params.id;


    let queryUpdate = `
    UPDATE table_name
    SET
    FIRSTNAME = '${req.body.FIRSTNAME}',
    FIRSTNAME = '${req.body.LASTNAME}',
    WHERE ID = ${id}
    `

    let connection;
    oracledb.outFormat = oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT;
    oracledb.autoCommit = true;

    try{
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
        const update = await connection.execute(queryUpdate);
        res.status(200).json({update})
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        next(error)
    }

}
```

Of cours I export this modules on the bottom of my controller.

I was thinking that might be fault format of my data fetched from backend. I've tried use `JSON.stringify(data)`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the data returned from your endpoint

```js
[{ "ID":1, "FIRSTNAME": "JOE", "SECONDNAME":"SMITH"}]
```

is not an object but an array.

you have to update your endpoint to return an object instead if you want to recieve only one element and not an array, However you can store only the first element of this array which is an object  :

```
setData(list[0])
```

then :

```js
setData({...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
```

should work as expected